# How do i compare byte arrays in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compare, arrays, equals

Ok all i want to do is compare 2 byte arrays in vb.net . I tried these codes:

```
If Byte.ReferenceEquals(bytearrayone, bytearraytwo) Then
  MsgBox("Yes", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
Else
  MsgBox("No", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If
```

And

```
If Array.ReferenceEquals(bytearrayone, bytearraytwo) Then
  MsgBox("Yes", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
Else
  MsgBox("No", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End If
```

Both byte arrays are the same, one array takes byte from a file from resources and the other from the computer. For testing purposes, I used the same file in both arrays but all I get is No according to the code provided. Both have the same lengths, i looped through both of them, both have same bytes at same points. Then what's wrong? What code should I use? Please help me.

Comment: `ReferenceEquals - Determines whether the specified System.Object instances are the same instance.` it doesnt compare array CONTENTS but whether the 2 references are the same .

Comment: Oh I see, so what code should i use to compare the contents, please tell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SequenceEqual

```
    Dim foo() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim barT() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim barF() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 5}

    Dim fooEqbarT As Boolean = foo.SequenceEqual(barT)
    Dim fooEqbarF As Boolean = foo.SequenceEqual(barF)

    Debug.WriteLine(fooEqbarT)
    Debug.WriteLine(fooEqbarF)
```

Compare two small files

```
    Dim path1 As String = "pathnameoffirstfile"
    Dim path2 As String = "pathnameofsecondfile"

    Dim foo() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path1)
    Dim bar() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path2)

    If foo.SequenceEqual(bar) Then
        'identical
    Else
        'different
    End If
```

Comment: I want to compare every single byte, not sequence from between. I dont want to loop through all, i want to do it in a blink of any eye, please help

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom since they are byte, that should work.  Otherwise, if you did not want to loop thru all, you shouldnt have used an array.

Comment: @Plutonix What else can I use to compare a file from resources and a local file?

Comment: what kind of file - what is the data?

Comment: @Afnan Makhdoom You would consider to mark this answer as 'accepted' and create a new question to your new doubt.

Comment: @ElektroHacker I think, i would continue in this thread, because it is still related to comparing to files

Comment: This falls under the category of good ways to do dumb things.  If it is so critical that the disk exe match the one embedded as a resource, just replace the disk one outright.  Or look at the date of it and decide whether or not to replace it.  Probably faster to replace it than to compare bytes PROVIDED that your app has permission to delete and write to the folder where the EXE is.

Comment: @Plutonix you actually misunderstood the scenario. i dont want to replace the file

Comment: Two files (or whatever) are equal when each byte in one of them equals the other. There is no other way to test for equality and therefore a `loop` is always needed (even the above code loops, though not in user code). There is no way to compare (large) files in "a blink of any eye".

Comment: Well, this was a great disappointment, i really need to compare every bit of the file quickly, looping through all those bytes will take hours... sigh :'(

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom: Looping through GBytes of data (in memory) takes less than a second if you do not run on some 6502 or 8086 CPU. Maybe you should make clear if you only need to compare TWO byte arrays or MANY? In case of many, create a Hash (MD5, CRC32, SHA512 ...) and then you only need to do it once for each image and then can search for equal hash values.

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom  How big are the files you are comparing and how are you reading them?

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom - I modified my answer above to show how this could be done for small files(28MB files are relatively small).  There is no point in creating a hash unless you are going to be comparing one file that never changes to other files.  If the file is large just modify the code to read equal size blocks from both files and use the same compare.  The slow part is going to be the actual reading of the file.

Comment: to be exactly precise, both arrays each take bytes from a 27.9 mb file. and please explain about hashes in detail, a lot detail :) , and suggest a exact, smart and a quick way to do it, this app will mainly run on quad cores and some other processors, thanks again for such an awesome support guys :) I really appreciate it

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom Did you read my previous comment or look at my modified answer?  If you look at the documentation (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=vb%20.net%20file%20hash&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&refinement=117&ac=5) you can find all you need to know about hashes, and even examples about doing file hashes.

Comment: @dbasnett yeah, your answer is just what I needed, exactly what i asked for thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to compare 2 files to see if the contents are the same, without regards to the information about the file (ie, modified date, name, type, etc.) you should use a hash on both the files. Here is some code I have used for a while. There are many ways to do this.

```
''' <summary>
''' Method to get a unique string to idenify the contents of a file.
''' Works on any type of file but may be slow on files 1 GB or more and large files across the network.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FI">System.IO.FileInfo for the file you want to process</param>
''' <returns>String around 50 characters long (exact length varies)</returns>
''' <remarks>A change in even 1 byte of the file will cause the string to vary 
''' drastically so you cannot use this to see how much it differs by.</remarks>
Public Shared Function GetContentHash(ByVal FI As System.IO.FileInfo) As String
    Dim SHA As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed()
    Dim sBuilder As System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim i As Integer
    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(FI.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)
        data = SHA.ComputeHash(fs)
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Close()
    End Using
    sBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
    ' Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    ' and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next i
    Return sBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

You need to run this on each file, to come up with a string that uniquely identifies the file, then compare the 2 strings.

Comment: If you have a group of files (a, b, c, d) and you want to know if a=b and c=d then generating a hash will take more time than just comparing the bytes.  If you want a=b, a=c, and a=d then there might be some time savings.

Comment: @Steve what does the "x2" mean in the last For loop?

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom - please make some attempt to do your own research.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: @Steve
' Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    ' and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
-_- seriously, still no clue about the x2, btw, got my answer! :D

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom - the link I posted will answer the ToString("x2") question.

Comment: Hashes are good for quickly identifying things which are not equal.  If one wants to find whether a disk contains any files which match any of 1,000 files which all have the same length, it may make sense to compare a *quick* hash of each proper-sized file on the disk against those of the 1,000 files to find candidate matches, but after finding a match one should generally check all the bytes of the apparently-matching files against each other to ensure the files really do match.  If the quick hash yields different values for all 1,000 files...

Comment: ...such an approach will outperform any hashing method which would take longer than doing a quick hash followed by a comparison, even if the fast hash identifies a false-positive match for every file and the slow hash has none.